# GPS Permission and Turn On GPS is required to get ScanResults and Bluetooth

Tags: android

I was developing an app that collects wifi scans, it was getting 0 length list of results in any android device running android 6 or higher, after that I realized that I have to ask for permission to use GPS or Location, so I have implemented it in my app, now the app only works if the GPS is on, else it gets 0 length  list of ScanResults, I have read the following discussion: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37060483 that is full with complaining of 
a lot of Android developers. 
I knew that the same problem exists at Bluetooth by the way.

**My Questions:** 
Have they at Android Team solved the problem, or they have a viewpoint I couldn't find? Have they fixed it in android 7.1 cuz they haven't in android 7.0? or Have they announced any news about this issue in the new Android 8.0?

Thank You?

Answer (score 0):

To get wifiscans without the GPS being turned on the only way as of now is to set the app's

`targetSDKVersion` to 21 or lower

You will get scan results even if the GPS is turned off for lolipop and above.

As for the Android Team solving this issue, I don't think they intend to fix this as most of the devs keep saying this is an intended behavior.

Comment: yeah, that is right but it does not make sense, I am actually wondering like all android developers 'what is the relation?' and the biggest question why this has been added it did not exist before, sorry I don't have reputations to mark your answer as correct :) thanks for anwering

Comment: I see no relation whatsoever either. Turning on GPS while scanning for  wifi just drains the battery. Another thing that I don't understand is why background wifi scanning is not allowed.